# How to change H2 Database password using command Line

Tags: database, h2

I would like to know whether there is a way we can change the H2 database password without login to the H2 Console.

Answer (score 0):

If you lost your password and and database was encrypted, you can't read it without password in any way.

If database wasn't encrypted, you can use the recovery tool to export its content into SQL script.

```
java -cp h2-*.jar org.h2.tools.Recover -dir PATH_TO_DIRECTORY -db DATABASE_NAME
```

After that can create a new database and use that script to import data by execution of SQL command it in

```sql
RUNSCRIPT FROM '/PATH_TO_DIRECTORY/DATABASE_NAME.h2.sql'
```

or with `RunScript` tool

```
java -cp h2-*.jar org.h2.tools.RunScript -url NEW_URL -user NEW_USER -password NEW_PASSWORD -script PATH_TO_SCRIPT
```

---

If you have a password but want to change it, you need to execute [`ALTER USER userName SET PASSWORD 'newPassword'`](https://h2database.com/html/commands.html#alter_user_set_password). You can do it from your application, or you can use a command-line shell tool:

```
java -cp h2-*.jar org.h2.tools.Shell
```

Comment: Didnt work for me.. RunScript still require the old password.

Comment: You need to specify a different database file. After that you need to delete an old database and rename a new one.